# Displaying live camera image in Qt GUI

Tags: qt, video, refresh, qimage, qlabel

Im trying to make an application that takes live image recorded by camera and shows it on screen using Qt GUI. The camera driver and api provides me with functionality that refreshes the memory block showed by pointer. 
The problem is my image won't refresh inside Qlabel made with Qimage (code below)

```
QImage myImage(raw_image_data_pointer, 768, 576, QImage::Format_RGB32   );
QLabel myLabel;

myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
myLabel.show();
```

How can i get my QLabel to be refreshed?

Comment: Have you tried showEvent/paintEvent/update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you create the label widget with a static image inside. The containing image is not "connected" to your camera anymore, but is just a copy of a frame of your video stream. In order to make `QLabel` to update itself, you have to constantly replace the containing image with new one. For example, you can set up a timer for that:

```
MyClass:MyClass()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(10); // Defines how often update the label.

    myLabel = new QLabel;
    [..]
}

// Slot
MyClass::update()
{
    QImage myImage(raw_image_data_pointer, 768, 576, QImage::Format_RGB32 );
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
}
```

Comment: Thanks it totally worked. I tried similar thing but with while loop instead of signal from timer, but from what read (and also experienced) there are problems with while loops blocking qt events loop. 
Can you think of any other way to refresh the screen instead of "every X time" ?

Comment: @MarcinKorn: It is important to note that you do not refresh the screen "every X time". The screen refresh is a different thing to your label "refresh". I cannot think of any other ways getting around to that other than catching the camera signal and trigger the update for that when data is available, but it might not make the rendering always busy. It depends on how you obtain these camera images, etc.